# Delete All duplicate value except one in MySQL Data Base Table

Tags: mysql

I want to delete all duplicate values except one on a MySQL database table:[image]

**What I tried:**

```
DELETE FROM employee WHERE Id NOT IN (
    SELECT MIN(Id) FROM (SELECT * FROM employee) AS employeeSub GROUP BY EmpName
)
```

Comment: i didn't get what is your requirement

Comment: Delete from employee where Id not in (select min(Id) from Employee group by EmpName). This is what you want

Comment: Weclome to SO. Rework your question if you want a good answer. Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to learn how to ask.

Comment: tnx mike..I am new here

Comment: I want to know how can i do this in ms sql server..how can i delete All duplicate value accept one ?? like Table is:

Comment: @NayasSubramanian

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can try this,

```
Delete from employee where Id not in (select min(Id) from Employee group by EmpName).
```

or you can use

```
WITH a as
(
SELECT EmployeeName,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION by EmployeeName ORDER BY EmployeeName) 
AS duplicateRecCount
FROM Employee
)
--Now Delete Duplicate Records
DELETE FROM a
WHERE duplicateRecCount > 1
```

Comment: just click on the up arrow and you can tick the asnwer

Comment: tick it us answer

Comment: Do you have any Idea about -->  How can I Implement SSO(Single Sign On) In My Spring mvc Based Java Web Application Using Saml2.0,Office 365 And Azure AD ?

Comment: i have implemented SSO with ADFS but i have done it with .Net.